# Trying to Calculate % of Total Column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, azure, subquery

I have a table that has populations by county and zip code. I needed to add up all of the zip codes to get the county population. Now that I have that, I need to show what percentage of the United States each county's population is.

Here's what I have so far:

```
select 
distinct "county_name", 
sum("ttl_pop") as county_pop
from neighborhood
group by county_name
```

How do I add a column to show what percentage of the total each county's population is?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `distinct`.  But the solution to your problem is to use window functions:

```
select county_name, sum(ttl_pop) as county_pop,
       sum(ttl_pop) / sum(sum(ttl_pop)) over ()
from neighborhood
group by county_name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Does anything need to go in the parenthesis after over ()? Unfortunately I got an error when I tried this

Comment: @klchase . . . Nope.  These treats the entire result set as the "partition" -- which means it sums the sum of `ttl_pop` from all rows.

Comment: This would be for MySQL versions 8.0 and higher.  Earlier versions don't support window functions.

Comment: @klchase . . . What version of MySQL are you running?  Azure supports 8.0 and I would recommend that you use the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql version is lower than 8.0 then window function will not work for you.

You need to use subquery as follows:

```
select county_name, sum(ttl_pop) as county_pop,
       sum(ttl_pop) / (select sum(tt.ttl_pop) from neighborhood tt) as avg_
  from neighborhood
 group by county_name;
```